# Python: Class and Subclass issue

Tags: python, class

I have this code:

```
class main():
    params = {}


class a(main):
    def __init__(self):
        self.params['test'] = "111aa"
        print self.params

class b(main):
    def __init__(self):
        self.params['be'] = "222bbb"
        print self.params

a()
#{'test': '111aa'}

b()
#{'test': '111aa', 'be': '222bbb'}
```

I need from b to print only `{'be': '222bbb'}`
Is there any way how to do it ?

Thanks

Comment: `params` is a class attribute. You want an instance attribute. Set `self.params` in `main.__init__`, and remember to invoke the superclass constructor in the subclass constructors.

Comment: Do you really want to share `params` between subclasses of `main`?

Comment: alecxe: Yes I need to share it; user2357112: Thank you!

Comment: How do you want to *share* `params` between the subclasses, but *not* have each subclass update the same `params`? This is a very confusing notion of "share" you have....

Comment: I have longer code this is only core of my problem

Comment: As a side note, `class main():` isn't illegal, but it will raise red flags to anyone who reads it. If you really want a classic class for some reason, the idiomatic way to write that is `class main:`. If you don't have any idea what that last sentence meant, you don't want a classic class; write `class main(object):`.

Comment: Calling your class `main` at all seems pretty bad form, in my book. It's not actually wrong, but other uses of `main` are sufficiently well-known and popular as to make it pretty confusing, and potentially troublesome if you ever inadvertently use this class in a program that really does have a `main` function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
class main(object): # use new-style classes!
    def __init__(self):
        self.params = {}

class a(main):
    def __init__(self):
        super(a, self).__init__()
        self.params['test'] = "111aa"
        print self.params

class b(main):
    def __init__(self):
        super(b, self).__init__()
        self.params['be'] = "222bbb"
        print self.params
```

Notice that in your code `params` was defined as a *class* attribute. By defining it in `__init__` of the superclass, we're stating that it's an *instance* attribute. Also notice that the subclasses call `__init__` on the superclass.

In this way, we're making sure that each instance has its own `params` attribute, without sharing it. You can't expect to share an object between instances and have each one with different values for it, it's a contradiction.

Comment: This is a good answer and a good explanation of the issue. My only suggestion would be to use `super()` to call `main`'s `__init__` method, rather than naming the super class explicitly. That's because `super` supports multiple inheritance, which is difficult or impossible otherwise.